# VSB relative path clashes with "refresh all"

Tags: vbscript, relative-path

I built a vbs script which "refresh all" and save a Master Workbook. The workbook contains many sheets and most of the sheets have queries linked to other workbooks.
The VBS script, the Master workbook and the many workbooks are all in the same folder (D:\TEST).

VBS script is simple:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open( fullpath & "\Master_Workbook.xlsx")

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save

objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close False


objExcel.Application.Quit
```

If the path to the Master_Workbook.xlsx is hardcoded, all is fine. The issue is when using "fullpath & ". The "refresh all" does not work anymore. I have the error message:

> [DataSource.Error] Could not find file
> 'C:\Users\my-username\Documents\workbook1.xlsx'

While all the files are in D:\TEST folder

Comment: i tired "path" and "thispath" same issue. I tried with "Master_Workbook.xlsx" only, same thing. it is like fullpath - path - thispath don't work really.

Comment: "path" or "fullpath" are no magic strings. They are simply empty variables you didn't initialize.

Comment: So how can I initialise them with the right path?

Comment: I managed to find another discussion on Stackoverflow and it works:

Comment: strFolder = Left(WScript.ScriptFullNAme, InStrRev(WScript.ScriptFullName, "\"))
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFolder & "\master_workbook.xlsx")

Comment: You might want to close this one as a duplicate of the other question that solved your problem.

Comment: I think i can only delete my question - I cannot find where to close it

Comment: If you post the url of the answer that helped you, someone else will be happy to vote to close it for you.